# Check for referential integrity break

Tags: mysql, referential-integrity

In my process, I do something like:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/mytable.txt' INTO TABLE mytable;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Now, I need to check that the data after this import is not breaking the referential integrity. I would like to do something like

```
check database all foreign_keys;
```

Is a similar command exists? If not, how to do this control?

Environment: MySQL v5.1.xx with InnoDB

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

[Here](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=11) is some code which does what you need. It looks like there's no such command.

### History

OK, I'm not a MySQL expert but referential integrity is managed constantly unless you disable it. You cannot insert a row into a table which violates a constraint unless you've dropped or disabled the constraint first. There's no need to "check" them.

<strike>If you did "disable" them, then enabling them will force a check.</strike>

This is in fact completely wrong and very scary indeed.
[at least in 5.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html)

I think if they had that function, they would just call it when you re-enabled the constraints, so I doubt you'll find it in the server.

Comment: The command: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; disable globally all referential integrity checks.    
This allows to import a bunch of data without taking care of the order of table imports.    

The command: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; enable globally all referential integrity checks. But as specified in the documentation, (can't find the page now) this will not force a check on existing data...

Comment: Wow. that's some scary sh!t then. You have a constraint that looks declarative but cannot be relied upon. I'd really doubt that until proven otherwise.

Comment: Thanks,
the script is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

The above link is dead, sadly.

The script mentioned in this blog post does a nice job of showing FKs which aren't referenced (though it will also show them when the FK is nullable, so may be legitimately null, so not always helpful!):

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/18/eventual-consistency-in-mysql/